# With Scala Salat (using mongodb casbah), how to store and load binary data?

Tags: scala, casbah, salat

I have a product case class defined in the way Salat expects.

```
case class Product(@Key("product_id") productId: String, 
                   @Key("png_image_binary") pngImageBinary: ???)
```

How can I add pngImageBinary so I can store this as a binary object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For binary data you can use `Array[Byte]`. It's equivalent of java `byte[]`, which maps to `Binary` BSON type. Check [java types](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-types/) and [BSON types](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/) from mongodb documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I tried @Key("png_image_binary") pngImageBinary: Seq[Byte] and it worked.